# Create a table with buttons and the files list of a directory

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have files in a directory.

I would like to know if it’s possible to create a table with the list of the files (only the name) and the data of creation? But in each line of the table, a button to open the file of this line.

Basically, a table with 3 columns (name, date, button), and the number of rows would vary depending on the number of files in the folder.

If it’s possible, how can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Daniel

Comment: How are you presenting this table to the user? Do you mean a Swing `JTable`?

Comment: Yes I use a Swing JTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For list of files,
   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()
2. I don't know about how to get creation date, but there is a function for getting lastmodifieddate().
   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()
3. To open with the button, on button click event execute,
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir \""+`<filename from first column>` + "\""); (IF your OS is windows)
4. To put all these in table,
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm

Comment: The availability of create date is going to be file-system specific. For example, NTFS (Windows) has it while ext3 (Linux) does not. Last modified date is pretty universally available. Perhaps the user could fall-back on it if create date isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows an easy way to add buttons to a column.

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039359) shows how to link file buttons in a tool bar with corresponding menu items.