# how to maintain history of recent files/folders inOpen Dialogbox in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to maintain history of last 5 or 6 open folder/files which i have recently opened in Open DialogBox as drop down list...how can I do it in java Swing???

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039359).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing that directly provides history in the `JFileChooser` API.  However, this old [JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip100.html) may give you the hints you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setSelectedFile(File file)` method of `JFileChooser`.

The doc says:

> public void setSelectedFile(File file)
>
> Sets the selected file. If the file's
>   parent directory is not the current
>   directory, changes the current
>   directory to be the file's parent
>   directory.
>
> Parameters: file - the selected file

Here is the [link for the doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [java preference api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html), to store previously opened folders/files. And also you shold customize JFileChooser  as suggested by [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216607/how-to-maintain-history-of-recent-files-folders-inopen-dialogbox-in-java-swing/5216854#5216854) to display these folders and files.