# How to integrate a JMenuBar in an MVC architecture in Java?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

I'm using this tutorial to build an application using the MVC architecture : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html. But I'm not sure how or where should I put the code to build and add actionListener of a JMenuBar inside of it.

Furthermore, the book Object-Oriented Design & Patterns by Cay Horstmann say "*The controller may process mouse and keyboard events from the windowing system, or it may contain user interface elements such as buttons and menus.*" Should I follow this advice, if yes, how should I implement it ? How to add it to the JFrame that is in my Main class ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would rather suggest you take a look at PM-based architecture, rather than MVC. Karsten Lentzsch has very good presentations about it (sorry I don't the link now) and also open source JGoodies binding library to help implement it.

Comment: Tank you @jfpoilpret, I was not aware of this architecture, I'll go look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [*How to Use Actions*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) is a convenient way to encapsulate this. Moreover, [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) "can be used to separate functionality and state from a component."

Addendum: In this very simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-corresponding/4039359#4039359), the model is a `File` representing a directory in a file system, and the view is a `JLabel` that listens for the `actionPerformed()`. The encapsulation afforded by [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) ensures that each menu item and tool bar button produce the same result. The approach is emblematic of Swing's [separable model architecture](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).

Comment: @mKorbel: Thanks! The convenience is compelling, but I still need to address the architecture aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I've always created MenuBars in the following way.

```
class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar {
   add(new FileItem())
}

class FileItem extends MenuItem {
    addMenuItem(new ExitAction())
}

class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
    //define the action, tooltip and name of here
}
```

then in your main frame you just add the menubar to it
    JFrame myframe;

```
myFrame.setMenuBar(new MyMenuBar())
```

Some of this syntax might be wrong, haven't written a menubar in a while. You can further extend it by having factory classes that return your actions so they can be reusable or use some DI framework to do the same thing