# Action when menu is opened

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenu

My friend is having trouble adding an action when a menu is opened. He won't ask for help from anyone so here I am.

The project is a tetris game. We need a system to run a pause method whenever a menu is opened and an unpause method when it is closed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swing - Take a look at [addMenuListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#addMenuListener%28javax.swing.event.MenuListener%29) and [addActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29).

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-corresponding/4039359#4039359).