# Setting a JPanel contained in a JDesktopPane as always on top

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I know this is a simple procedure with `JInternalFrame`, but can it be done with a measly `JPanel`?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on just what it is you're trying to achieve? Why are you trying to place a JPanel directly in a JDesktopPane? Will this JDesktopPane hold other JInternalFrames and are they supposed to be under the JDesktopPane? Have you considered using a JLayeredPane to hold the JDesktopPane and then adding your JPanel to the layered pane (or using the glass pane)?

Comment: Sure, I have a JDesktopPane with several JinternalFrames that the client can  interact with. In the corner of the desktop is a JPanel that acts as a toolbar (has some icons). Naturally this toolbar should always be on top. Need I convert it to an internal frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the tool bar is sitting across one of the sides of the GUI, why try to add the toolbar directly to the JDesktopPane?  Why not hold everything in a JPanel that uses BorderLayout, add the JDesktopPane to this JPanel BorderLayout.CENTER and add the toolbar to the JPanel BorderLayout.WHATEVER (depending on where you want to place it)?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `JPanel` for your toolbar, consider [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) in conjunction with `Action`. Conveniently, a [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) is detachable on most platforms. There are related examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-corresponding/4039359#4039359) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/2e1b14bcad9bd7fa).