# switching between different JPanels when pressing jtoolbar buttons 

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jtoolbar

Im designing a parent *Jpanel* contains *JToolBar* && *inner JPanel*.By the *JToolBar's* action i need to replace the *inner JPanel* with *new JPanel* which where i designed already. **switching between different JPanels when pressing jtoolbar buttons**.
 How can I do that in **NetBeans IDE**?

```
final CardLayout c = new CardLayout();
    jPanel2 = new JPanel(c);
    jPanel2.add(new BarChartPanel(), "CHART");
    jPanel2.add(new ReportViewPanel(), "REPORT");
    ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    java.net.URL imageURL = cldr.getResource("Images/barimages.jpg");
    ImageIcon aceOfDiamonds = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
    JButton btnChart = new JButton(aceOfDiamonds);
    btnChart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            c.show(jPanel2, "CHART");

        }
    });
    jToolBar1.add(btnChart);
    jToolBar1.addSeparator();
    jToolBar1.setFloatable(false);
```

Here 'jPanel2' is my inner panel but while clicking the toolbars's button it's not diplaying!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (like the one linked in my answer - it is an SSCCE).

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Can you ask it using different words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to change these panels in the main panel's inner panel.

Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for the layout of the "main panel's inner panel", as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

Comment: +1 for `CardLayout`; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-correspondin/4039359#4039359) using `Action` and `JToolbar`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But im having problem in displaying a new panel in an inner panel area.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple panel, you might want something like this : (Not a perfect code,but this is the way,i'm just pointing you the way) :

```
 public class MultiPanels {

    private JScrollPane getContent() {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(300,200);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(getPanel(d,  6, Color.red));

    }

    private JScrollPane getPanel(Dimension d, int rows, Color color) 
        {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(color);
    }     
 }
```

and now, in the question, *change the look of the main panel*  if you mean to change the *look and feel*, its not possible, and if you mean to just change the appearance,say background, you can do that by overriding the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Actually i want to change the inner panel of the main panel while JToolbar button clicks.

Comment: "Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding paint()."—[The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).