# Horizontal clickable Menu

Tags: java, swing, menu, clickable

I would like to create a horizontal clickable Menu as in the Microsoft Powerpoint or Word.

For example, when 'insert' JButton clicked, I want to see options to be clicked. 
So the user can choose any of the JMenuItems below the 'insert'/any menu.

Thanks for your helps in advance..

Answer (score 4):

maybe [JPopupMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup), another examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0460__JPopupMenu.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You might need [JMenuBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html) and
[JMenuItem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html)

Answer (score 2):

[`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) is particularly flexible for this, as you can add other components. See also [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) and this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-correspondin/4039359#4039359).