# Swing: Tabs menu like in Firefox/Thunderbird settings, with caption below icon

Tags: java, swing, menu

Is it somehow possible to create a tab menu in the style of the Firefox/Thunderbird preferences dialog via Swing?
So it should be like the JTabbedPanel, but without visible tab borders and the icons should be below.
I have to admit that I am a bit new to Swing btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) might be a suitable choice, as shown in [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038605/swing-link-toggle-buttons-together-with-a-button-group-along-with-correspondin/4039359#4039359) that shows how to use `Action` in this context.