# Changing setText from multiple classes in java

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm busy with an application which runs in a `JFrame` (using `BorderLayout`), and has:

- A status bar at the bottom
- Fixed Buttons on the left
- Menu on top (which change relating to specific function),
- Buttons on the right (which change relating to specific function).

I'm setting it up that for every button on the left, a separate class file will be created for its functions and procedures. At this stage it's about 8 extra classes.

How to go about changing the values on the buttons and menu for each class, by that specific class?

Comment: One way might be to give each class a method like `public Action[] getActions()` that returns the actions appropriate to the class.  On loading/changing to that functionality, call the method and add them to the tool-bar or menu.

Comment: @AndrewThompson has the correct insight; see also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a separate class for each button, I would make sure that the class extends `JButton`. By doing this, to change the values on the buttons, you still have access to all the normal `JButton` methods like `setText();`

So hopefully your custom button classes would look something like this...

```
public class MyButton1 extends JButton {

    public MyButton1(String label){
        super(label);
    }

// your other methods go here
}
```

To create the button you would do this, which would set the button label...

```
MyButton1 button1 = new MyButton1("Hello");
```

And you can still call `JButton` methods if you want to change the label later, like this...

```
button1.setText("Goodbye");
```