# How to make List with all files in folder using swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to make a list with filename from a folder and show all the files that are present in that folder with a particular extension. I want the list to be selectable so that I can select and delete the file from the list or edit it. I know how to select all files from a folder but don't know how to show it in [GUI](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/list-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-particular-dire.html).

```
File folder = new File("c:/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply create a JList and add the file names to the list's DefaultListModel?

Comment: Please see: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: For tips see the [File Browser GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui).

Comment: @Hov Why a `String`?  Using `File[]` and a renderer generally works better.

Comment: @Andrew: Yep you're right as that gives you much greater freedom on what can be done with the information held by the JList. You would likely want to create your own renderer to that it displays in a pretty way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is what I did!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) shows how to enumerate the files in a directory and display them in a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) and a [`JMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). You can use an `Action`, such as `RecentFile`, to encapsulate behavior for use in your [`ListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

Comment: very helpful for a starter :)

Answer (score 1):

You get all the file name from folder with extension and construct a string
array out of that.Then use a JList to populate in swing.For example something 
like below

```
String options = { "apple.exe", "ball.exe" "cat.exe"};
JList optionList = new JList(options);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

See JFileChooser (shameless copy of the JFileChooser help page):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

See the FilenameFilter?

setMultiSelectionEnabled (true); is another hint.

Location: java/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html