# Creating a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, oop, layout

My main class displays a JMenuBar. This JMenuBar is managed from "calculator.ui.MenuBar."

```
public JMenuBar createMenuBar() 
{
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    new calculator.ui.MenuBar(menuBar);
    return menuBar;
}
```

MenuBar creates my "File" JMenu and "Insert" JMenu.

```
public MenuBar(JMenuBar menuBar)
{
    new FileMenu(menuBar);
    new InsertMenu(menuBar);
}
```

FileMenu contains all the options for "File." In the File class, there is a JMenuItem called "New Calculator." Now, when you click "New Calculator," I want the JPanel in my main class to create an instance of Calculator in my main class.

```
newFileSubMenu = new JMenu("New...");
calculatorFileSubMenu = new JMenuItem("New Calculator");

calculatorFileSubMenu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "New Calculator");

newFileSubMenu.add(calculatorFileSubMenu);

ActionListener newCalculatorListener = new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
       newCalculator();
    }
};
calculatorFileSubMenu.addActionListener(newCalculatorListener);
```

This is the code for my main class JPanel:

```
public Container createContentPane() {
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    return contentPane;
}
```

My questions are related to the design of my program. For each instance of Calculator, I want to:

1. Create a JPanel within the main JPanel that contains my Calculator (what stumps me here is how do I - from my FileMenu class - create a JPanel that's in my main class?).
2. Make sure that the Calculator object refreshes.

Note: I also want my JPanels to be in TabbedPanes (if that changes anything; if it doesn't, then I can figure that part out once I know the answer for the first question.)

Thanks for your help, I hope I've been clear enough in what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your menu item's [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), you can use [`setSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) on your [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) to select the pane holding an existing calculator instance. You can use [`setComponentAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setComponentAt%28int,%20java.awt.Component%29) to replace the content of any tab with an instance of your calculator.

There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Comment: I followed your path and changed my constructors for my Menus to include my main JPanel. Then, when I hit the "New Calculator" button, I used JTabbedPane.addTab to create the tab. Thank you!