# I thought that java interfaces could hold a subclass, but maybe not in ActionListener... correct?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

The issue could be different then what I suspect, but I figure the problem is either I read wrongly when learning about interfaces or it applies differently inside of the action listener.

First off, here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to main.GUI
    at main.GUI$3.actionPerformed(GUI.java:224)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
this.select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((GUI) e.getSource()).tool = new Selection();
            }
        });
```

I have an interface called tool, which I make a global variable Tool tool; for the GUI class. Then I attempt in the method above to assign the Selection class to the var tool which implements Tool. Am I doing something wrong and how do I fix it? If you need more code just ask.

Also When I assign a new Selection() to the global var tool outside of the ActionListener it works... so that is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the button inside of a toolbar.

Use [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), to encapsulate functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding

> I thought that java interfaces could hold a subclass, but maybe not in ActionListener… correct?

No, this has nothing to do with your problem. Rather your problem is an incorrect cast pure and simple. The object returned by `e.getsource()` is not a GUI object but rather an AbstractButton, perhaps a JButton (it's the variable named "select"). The component that has the ActionListener added to it is the one that is returned by `ActionEvent#getSource()`.

Also, I don't see where you have an interface holding a subclass anywhere.

could you do?:

```
    this.select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tool = new Selection(); //??
        }
    });
```

It's hard to say what you should do as we really don't know what the structure of the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: That makes sense. I have the button inside of a toolbar. Is there anyways I could get out into the GraphicalUserInterface where I have all my global variables? What are my options? I can provide you with the whole class.

Comment: You need references to whatever objects you want to access. Try not to use the term "global variable" around a Java programmer. They really don't exist in the Java world. Perhaps you mean *class fields*.

Comment: I suppose you could pastebin your code if it isn't too large.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JHcfJNmS Here is the class, error is on line 224. If you see anything else then let me know of course. Thanks!

Comment: ALSO, note that Tool is an interface and Selection implements Tool. I assume that is a subclass of it. I might be wrong in my terminology, if so... sorry.

Comment: @Zevesco: missing several framework classes, Mapper, Tool, impl.Selection.

Comment: @Zeveso: oh, and this line doesn't make sense: `((GUI) e.getSource()).getParent() = new Selection();`. It's not Java.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ftSsMtWk It is java, but is my user defined class. GUI is what I have you before and it worked for one of the other action listeners, but not that one. I think it was because in another tool bar. ANYWAYS, here you go with a new pastie and I am looking into the Action class, but still don't quite understand it... just give me some time... lost power again for a bit so I can only do so much at a time