# Dynamic Java.swing Menu

Tags: java, dynamic, menu

I have a special problem in coding a dynamic menu in Java.

What I want:
I want a menubar that looks for special files (example: addon01_men.class) and adds the content of this file to the menu as a new item.

Problem:
To invoke the methode/class in the file, I've to invoke it in the main file. But the addon-class is needed in this case, because java checks the presence of the methode/class. So the program will not start, if "addon01_men.class" is missing.

My solutions didn't work (perhaps in my fault):
- Reflections
- Override

I don't want to use dynamic classes because it's necessary to compile when the program starts - because not all PCs that can run java, can compile java.

I'd be pleased when someone has a working idea.
Thank you.

Comment: [`FileMenu`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) may be of interest.

Comment: yes. thats interesting. but not that is not what I search. Thank you for help. I try to explain more closely: The main-program has a JMenu. In the File "addon01_men.class" is a additional menupoint: `class addon01_men extends JMenuItem implements ActionListener
    {
        public addon01_men ()
        {
            super ("Add01");
  addActionListener (this);
        }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
  new addon01_pl();
        }
    }` I need a solution to invoke "addon01_men", if "addon01_men.class" is in the folder, but do not, when its not (the NOT is the problem)

Comment: You can use `Action` to encapsulate your reflective code. Please edit your question, where new code will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You should start simple like this example using Reflections:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/
For want you want, you need look for a directory containing the class files like addon01_men.class (think like they're plugins), load them and create instances.

Comment: That helps me a lot, thank you. I tried a lot with this and it seems it could work nearly. Problem is with this I can invoke methods. So I tried to make methods to add(addon01_men); ... but this don't work. I need to invoke classes/constructor... I found something after that on [link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html[/link]. But thats a little bit freaky.

Comment: @MarcelKrammer Reflection in Java is ugly.  That is what you need, though, for the question you asked.  Either use [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) to call a no-argument constructor, or [`Class.getConstructor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) to get a Constructor object on which you can call [`.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) with arguments.

Comment: @dsh thank you. Sorry for the many bones you guys have to throw me, but I think I only need a line, that has an effect like "add(new obj)"... if obj is an instance of a constructor... found nothing in JavaDoc...