# Create multiple menubars with icons in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I am working on a Swing application in which I have to create multiple menubars on clicking a menu.
     The other menubar either should be added or removed from the container.

I have to use an icon above and below text in the menu, but I have not found a suitable constructor for it.

Is it possible to have a back and forward button in a `JMenu` that should work as the back and forward buttons work in a browser? They should display the previous view of window, preferably without multiple displays.

Comment: Posting the relevant section of your code or better an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would help us help you better :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean *menu bar*? Your buttons sound more like a *tool bar* thing.

That said, a [`JMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) is just a special kind of button, so perhaps you can derive your own custom menu class from that, in order to paint top level menus in a different way. For the [main menu bar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar%28javax.swing.JMenuBar%29), some platforms (Mac OS in particular) probably won't handle the custom painting code, as that menu bar is handled by native OS code. But for a second menu bar, which gets painted by swing, I'd expect no problems. After all, a [`JMenuBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html) is just a `Component`.

Comment: I think that s/he look for Accordion, but JToolBar is one of the ways +1

Answer (score 1):

If you go with multiple instances of [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), you can add each one to a different panel of [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Just use two JPanels.

Here is some code that I wrote a few minutes ago for the start of a shop GUI.

```
public Shop() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    {
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    final JTextField coins =  new JTextField("Coins: " + TerrainDemo.money); 
    coins.setForeground(Color.red);
    menu.add(coins);
    panel.add(menu);
    }
    {
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    final JTextField coins =  new JTextField("Coins: " + TerrainDemo.money); 
    coins.setForeground(Color.red);
    menu.add(coins);
    panel_1.add(menu);
    }
}
```

Which results in:

[image]