# Buttons disappear from the JToolbar when I drag it

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I'm having problem with my JToolBar. It contains many buttons

[image: buttons]

The problem is that when I drag the toolbar, the buttons disappear and its width is a constant "126 pt" that I can not change in the dimensions.

[image: problem]

How can I change the dimensions "or resize" it when I drag it?

Comment: Please post the code, so we can help you better

Comment: Try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), which does _not_ exhibit the problem you mention.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note the example by @trashgod is just 75 LOC.

Answer (score 1):

Window that appears when toolbar is being dragged takes its size from JToolbar preferred size. It seems that you have hardcoded its size or you have some incorrect layout that gives a wrong preferred width.

Anyway, i cannot say anything more specififc without seeing the code that presents this problem.

Comment: +1 for [likely prospect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).