# 'Recently Opened' i.e. History type functionality in java swing

Tags: java, swing

Can any one suggest me the basic steps to make a 'Recently Opened' i.e. History type functionality in Java Swing using `JScrollPane,` JTextArea` and so on.

What ever different frames like `frame1`, `frame2`, `frame3` etc, we open its name will be listed dynamically in this text area which  is a part of main screen(a main jframe).
If we click on any one of list generated in the 'Recently opened' text area that corresponding frame will show again.

Kindly reply, I need it in my project. Please see the figure here:

[image: figure]

Thanks.

Comment: kindly let us know what have you tried? We dont need it for our  own project

Comment: Scroll down to [`RecentFile`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), for example.

Answer (score 0):

If the history is for a single object like a tabbed pane (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), you can making a subclass of the class and overloading the selection method, to create a history element.

The question is a bit vague, so it is hard to be more specific. But you should likely look towards overloading methods in whatever classes you will be using.

Comment: Thanks Martin for reply. But I'm not using tabbed pane. I'm simply using  jframe. please see the figure I attached.

Comment: Sorry as new user I'm unable to attach img. Please see the figure here: http://i45.tinypic.com/r2j9rr.jpg

Comment: I might have been unclear. One way to do this would be to subclass the menues where you perform your actions, and make those create some sort of history element when they are activated.