# JMenu work on single tab

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jmenubar

I have a `JMenuBar` and I have a `JTabbedPane`, when I create multiple tabs the `JMenuBar` does it on all the tabs, e.g. I open a file it opens the same file in each tab.

However I only want it to open a file on the current tab. I have added a `ChangeListener` so It know what tab its in however it does not seem help even though it works.

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tab=" + tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
    }
});
getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, "Center");
pack();
```

I want to be able to have multiple tabs open while the menu bar only corresponds to current tab.

Comment: Can you provide some example code to show how you are loading the file and setting the tab content?

Comment: I cant upload any code due to security risks, but I any information would be helpful. So far the only way I think of doing it is by adding the menubar in the Tab, however this is more complicated and does not look nice. I was wondering if there is a way to link the menubar with the current tab only. as the changelistener chooses where the tab is. Thanks

Comment: Without an example of your problem, it's going to be impossible to provide you with assistance...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Let the object providing the content of each tab export it's own specific instances of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). When the user changes tabs, use `setAction()` to set the desired action of each available `JMenuItem` in the global menu. There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).