# Java ActionListener in another Class

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener, jmenu

I am trying to build a small notepad application using the Java Swing library. I have a main function which calls a constructor of `JFrame (NotepadClass)`. In this `NotepadClass` I have a `MenuDesigner` class something like this:

```
this.setJMenuBar(new MenuDesigner());
```

The `MenuDesigner` class extends `JMenuBar` which calls actionListener (`MenuActionListener`) which is written in another class.
Now my question is: If I click on "new" `menuItem`, the title which is in `NotepadClass` should change. How do I access a class that is two levels up?

Which concept of Java should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

- use [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead of [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), this API is designed for your purpose
- post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue, just about [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) with [JMenuBar, JMenu and one, two JMenuItem(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), noting else

Comment: +1 for `Action`. Also consider the approach outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14095900/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to give a definitive answer, but one of the reasons to write a separate class to build your menu is that you can pass instances to the class.

```
this.setJMenuBar(new MenuDesigner(notepadClass));
```

This is one reason why it's good to have a model class or classes when you're building a GUI.

You can pass an instance of the highest level model class to all of your GUI components, and each component can get or set the parts of the model class that they represent.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass down the NotepadClass in the constructors and provide a method to change the title.

Another option is to build the ActionListener inside the NotepadClass or let NotepadClass itself implement the Actionlistener interface so you can access the variables or methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your actionListener for your menu in another class?

You could [create a new class that `implements ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) in which you can add you own logic. This way you can reuse it in another file.

Also, you should probably de-couple your `MenuDesigner` class by moving it into its own file.