# How to add a menu bar for loading/saving files in a class that extends JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu, jpanel

Consider the following code :

```
/**
 * Main class
 * @author X2
 *
 */
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener ,KeyListener
{
    /**
     *    private variables
     */

    // dimensions of the window
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Dimension MIN_DIM = new Dimension(300, 300);
    private static final Dimension PREF_DIM = new Dimension(500, 500);


    /**
     * Setting the dimensions of the window
     */
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return MIN_DIM; }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return PREF_DIM; }



    /**
     *  The constructor
     */
    DrawingPanel()
    {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
// code 
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) 
{ // code 

}

// more code
```

How can I add a panel to my window , where I need the options for opening and saving files .

At the moment the window looks like that : 
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [`JMenuBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) or a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) to the enclosing `JFrame`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Answer (score 3):

add [JMenuBar to the JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMenuBar%28java.awt.MenuBar%29), not to the `JPanel(add JMenuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH)` (is possible, no issue, maybe not proepr of way)

Answer (score 3):

This depends.

You could use a `BorderLayout`, placing the `JMenuBar` at the `NORTH` position

The problem then comes down to how do you layout any child components?  You'd need one kind of content pane, this would allow to set a different layout manager for the container at the `CENTRE` position

Alternatively, you could use [`SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29) to find the first instance of `JFrame` in the parent component hierarchy or [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29) if you mind casting the result.

**Updated**

It just occurred to me, if you were going to use `getAncestorOfClass`, you would be better off looking for an instance of `JRootPane`, which has a `setJMenuBar`. It is the responsibility of the `JRootPane` to layout out the menu bar and content pane (and a few other things)