# How to make a array of a method accessible out

Tags: java, arrays, swing, button

i have  a method that create a array with some path to files...

and in the program i will press a button "Next Page", to show tem next item in the array[1] array[2]...

but the event of the button Next Page Cant access the array created inside the metlhod

i know how to pass the array between methods, but how to make a button event to access it ?!

the code is so big but its something like this:

```
    public class gui {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         ->>>>>     i want the array accessible from here,

        }
public void geraListaArquivos(String subdir, String matricula) {
....
....

....
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
...
....
}


}
```

i want the access of the values in ListOfFiles, at the ActionPerfomed, how can i do this ;x?

Comment: i don't understand your code example, could you coded it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Any Specific reason for using Arrays[] ? **Use an ArrayList.**

If you need to use Arrays specifically, just replace the ArrayList by arrays.

```
public class gui {

       public static List<String> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<String>();


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         ->>>>>     i want the array accessible from here,

            // Access the listOfFiles Here.
            for(int count=0; count<listOfFiles.size(); count++)
            { 
                // DO YOUR OPERATION HERE 
            }

        }
      public void geraListaArquivos(String subdir, String matricula) {
      ....
      ....

      ....
      listOfFiles.add("FileName");
      ...
      ....
      }


}
```

Let me know if it you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to exposing the array, consider using [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the `File` and its `ActionListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513). This will make it easier to localize the code shared by buttons and menu items. In this way, you can allow the user to operate on `File` instances individually, rather than sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Move your listOffFiles declaration outside the method.  Then you can still populate it from the geraListaArquivos method and access it from your event handler like so:

```
public class gui {

    private File[] listOfFiles = null;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // do something with listOfFiles here

    }

    public void geraListaArquivos(String subdir, String matricula) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
        listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    ....
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move listOfFiles outside the "geraListaArquivos". You have various alternatives:

1 - ) You can put in a class variable.
2 - ) You can put in a instance variable.
3 - ) You can extract to another class, accesible for both methods.
4 - ) You can do a inner class.
and go on...

You must choose what is better for your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an Image that looks like a button. Then try asking in a Thread: If mouseX is bigger than buttonX and less than buttonX+buttonLength and mouseY is bigger than buttonY and less than buttonY+buttonLength, you can call your methode( perhaps buttonIsPressed();). I hope it helps.