# CardLayout: How to show panels in one class in the ActionListeners in another class?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I added my `buttons` in a `JPanel` (which has a `border layout`, added the buttons to its `south` position), then added `another JPanel` `cardsPanel` in the (`center` position of the) parent panel, and gave it a `CardLayout`. *I want this `cardsPanel` to be the `container` for the cards* (I mean the panels which will share the same screen space).

Now what I need to do is to to display those cards (I am calling the panels which will share the same screen space as cards) as a response to the buttons in the parent panel. But the buttons are located in the parent panel and their action listeners will obviously be located there too.

**So the question is that how do I `show` (by `cardLayout.show()`) the panels located in a container class (with `Cardlayout`) as a response to buttons located in another class (with `BorderLayout`) ?**

---

**EDIT - QUESTION ABOUT ACTION:-**

I hope to find implementing an `Action` more useful than an `ActionListener`. *I also read that they can be reused, and used for the buttons which perform the same function.* I have a few buttons which perform the function of flipping a particular card (i.e. displaying a particular panel in the CardLayout). **I have written just one inner class and I want to use it for all the buttons.**

So I will like to pass the button identifier (the string used to identify a button when we add the button to its parent e.g. `String btnIdentifier= "1"; panel.add(button1, btnIdentifier);` ) to the method actionPerformed() of this class, eventhough we are never explicitly calling actionPerformed(). **So how can I pass the string identifier of the button to the actionPerformed() method so that I can use the same `Action` for all my buttons.**

**Minimal Code:-**

```
class Action extends AbstractAction{
            Action(String text, ImageIcon icon){
                super(text, icon);

            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button1.setBorderPainted(true);
                button1.setContentAreaFilled(true);
                if (btnIdentifier=="1"){  //////ASSUMING THAT BUTTON IDENTIFIER HAS SOMEHOW BEEN PASSED TO THIS METHOD
                    FirstCard firstCard= new FirstCard();
                    cardsPanel.add(firstCard, btnIdentifier);
                    cardLayout.show(cardsPanel, btnIdentifier);
                } else if (btnIdentifier=="2"){  //////ASSUMING THAT BUTTON IDENTIFIER HAS SOMEHOW BEEN PASSED TO THIS METHOD
                    SecondCard secondCard= new SecondCard();
                    cardsPanel.add(secondCard, btnIdentifier);
                    cardLayout.show(cardsPanel, btnIdentifier);
                } else if (btnIdentifier=="3"){  //////ASSUMING THAT BUTTON IDENTIFIER HAS SOMEHOW BEEN PASSED TO THIS METHOD
                    ThirdCard thirdCard= new ThirdCard();
                    cardsPanel.add(thirdCard, btnIdentifier);
                    cardLayout.show(cardsPanel, btnIdentifier);
                } 
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the desired functionality. Make a reference to the enclosing panel visible, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063037/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513); or export the `Action` from a class having (at least) [*package-private*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513).

Comment: See also *Card Layout Actions*, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657106/230513).

Comment: I have a follow-up question about `Action`, I have added it to my question. Will be great if you can answer that. Thank you.

Comment: Look at `ActionEvent`; use `getActionCommand()` to learn the command name and `getSource()` to determine which object sent the message.