# Can I add multiple frames in CardLayout in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have five `JFrame`s in my program. I want those to be in a `CardLayout`.
Suppose `A` is the main frame and `B,C,D,E` are sub-frames.
Now, I want to put four buttons in `A` which will open the sub-frames individually. All the sub-frames will have a 'Back' button to go back to main frame. How do I do this in `CardLayout`? **Let me know if there's any other layout to do so.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a `JFrame` is a [*top-level container*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). Presumably, each of your existing frames sets or adds a container to the *content pane*, so you can add *those* containers to the [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Several examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20CardLayout). Also consider a `JToolBar`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), for your navigation panel.