# Send the file.getAbsolutePath() from JFileChooser as a parameter to another button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I have a small problem with a Java app. I'm using a `JFileChooser` to open up a text file, display its content on a textzone, while keeping it ready for some other actions.

One of these actions are calling a method when pressing an 'analyse' button in my GUI. My problem is that it seems like I can't change the header of the action listeners on the `JFrame` class, in order to put the `file.getAbsolutePath()` as an out from the `JFileChooser` to the buttons action listener.

Below is the code I have. Basically I want the "test.txt" to be replaced with the file I open in the `JFileChooser`.

How do I solve this problem ?

```
  private void OuvrirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
            textarea.read(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()), null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("problem accessing file" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
    }
}                                      

private void FermerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    System.exit(0);         // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void traiterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    Reader readme = new Reader();
    ArrayList<String[]> Noms = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    readme.file2string("test.txt", Noms);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

edit : I solved the issue. All I had to do was to use the fileChooser.getSelectedFile() everytime I needed to use the file elsewhere.

Comment: Post some code about your problem. The description is too vague.

Comment: Use `Action`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), to encapsulate the `File`.

Comment: *"edit : I solved the issue."* Congrats on solving the problem. :)  Don't enter answers into the question. Either create your own answer below, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. All I had to do was to use the fileChooser.getSelectedFile() everytime I needed to use the file elsewhere.